# JS docs, what does [ and ]] mean in the docs?

Tags: javascript

I was reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map and I stumbled pretty quickly when I got to this documentation:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
  // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

What is the context of `[` and `]]` in terms of trying to understand how the function works as a callback?

[image]

Comment: Optional arguments. You can see them marked as such in the [Parameters section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters)

Comment: There is no `[[` and you will never see one, that would make no sense. You only see multiple concurrent `]` because they're matching the opening `[` spread out between several optional arguments.

Comment: "The square brackets mean that the enclosed parameter is optional" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Structures/Syntax_sections#Constructors_and_methods

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets in documentation is a common notation for optional elements. It means that the `, array` bit, and even the `, index, array` bit can be left off. Thus, this is a shortcut for:

> `function callback(currentValue)` or
>   `function callback(currentValue, index)` or
>   `function callback(currentValue, index, array)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it took me a while to understand too.

For the documentation of [Array.protoype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) here

The syntax is `arr.slice([begin[, end]])`

The begin and end are optional parameters.

So all of these are valid

```
arr.slice();
arr.slice(begin);
arr.slice(begin,end);
```

Most of get confused by `[,` this just means separation by commas if the optional parameter is included i.e, `begin,end`